# Trouble with quotes and optional wildcard in R, regex

Tags: r, regex

Given this character vector

```
columnsToKeep <- c("W","L","Customer Rate", "Diff% from Base",
               "StoreOcc%", "COMPPS","Avail","Days in Unit",
               "DSRC","Rec New Price", "Rec Rate Chg",
               "intScheduledMoveOuts","TI30","BR1Yr",
               "RLMI","NM7D","Last Rate Change %", "Occ%", 
               "Last Rate Change Amt", "BR", "MoveInRate",
               "newRate",
               "lengthOfStay", "mnyRentAtMoveIn", 
               "rentPriorToRateChange","mnyRentAtMoveOut","status")
```

I attempt this code

```
d<-columnsToKeep[grepl(" ", columnsToKeep)]

cat(gsub("(\\%?\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s*\\w*)", '`\\1`+', d))
```

which produces

```
`Customer Rate`+ Diff% `from Base`+ `Days in Unit`+ `Rec New Price`+ `Rec Rate Chg`+ `Last Rate Change`+ % `Last Rate Change`+ Amt
```

but I want this

```
`Customer Rate`+ `Diff% from Base`+ `Days in Unit`+ `Rec New Price`+ `Rec Rate Chg`+ `Last Rate Change %` + `Last Rate Change Amt`
```

Clearly I am having a hard time providing the correct regex for the % sign.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex at all - just `paste` it together: `paste0("\`", paste(columnsToKeep[grepl(" ", columnsToKeep)], collapse="\` + \`"), "\`")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so sure what you are trying to do with your regular expression, but it looks like you want to put backticks around each name in d and then join them with +.  Two ways to get that are:

```
cat(sapply(d, function(s) { paste0("`", s, "`") }), sep="+ ")
```

And

```
cat(gsub("$", "`", gsub("^", "`", d)), sep="+ ")
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you're just looking for entries that contain at least one space in between words. You can give this a try: `"([\w%]+ [\w%]+(?: [\w%]+)*?)"`

It looks like you're only trying to match letters and `%`, so using `\w` might be a bit dangerous (it also matches `0-9` and `_`). You can be more specific with `"([A-Za-z%]+ [A-Za-z%]+(?: [A-Za-z%]+)*?)"`

Also, note that `\s` doesn't just mean a space (). It's the set of *all* whitespace characters so it will also match newlines, carriage returns, and tabs. If you want to match a space, just use a literal space.